# How can I change the day in a date string?

Tags: ruby

I have a string variable with a date like this:

```
@date = "2016-09-01"
```

And I have another variable with a day like this:

```
@day = 5
```

How can I change the day of the date using `@day` value?

I need this result:

```
@date = "2016-09-05"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to work with the plain string, you can just replace the last 2 characters from the date string like this:

```
@date[-2..-1] = @day.to_s.rjust(2, "0")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
@date = '2016-09-01'.to_date
@day = 5
DateTime.new(@date.year, @date.month, @day).to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Convert to a date, update date component, reformat as string.
2. Use a regular expression to replace just the date component.

Converting to a date is probably the safer option, as it will take locale settings into account. (eg: MM/DD/YYYY formats vs. DD/MM/YYYY formats)

Converting Date to string, updating day component reformat as a string:

```
require 'date'
d = Date.parse(@date)
Date.new(d.year,d.month,@day).to_s
```

Regexp solution:

```
@date.sub!(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-)\d{2}$/, '\1' + "%02d"% @day)
```